# Is it possible to have a counter-review if suspended incorrectly from bad review audit?

Tags: feature-request, review-suspension

When you review questions that seem kind of "off-topic" or "unsalvageable" but they are a test that has been automatically generated from questions with a high vote, you will get suspended from reviewing.

However, sometimes the questions have been voted highly and they are good questions, but they are also off-topic.

So, it would be good if there was have some kind of counter-audit system that lets the user counter a poor audit, giving the reason, and letting a moderator judge the situation instead of system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can already discuss poor review audits on the meta site of the site that you got the review.

Meta Stack Overflow has a specific tag for this: [disputed-review-audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits)

You can provide links to the audits that you failed and discussion can take place regarding the review audits. This allows the community to discuss the audit rather than just a single moderator.

Should the community agree that you have been suspended incorrectly, a moderator can remove the suspension.